# JavaScript Plug In for Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an ASP.NET project, and it is very frustrating how poor the support for JavaScript is in VS. For example, no outlining, no f12 to find a definition, no refactoring, no code analysis, no ready support for documenting functions, horrible navigation and barely functional intelisense.

Although JavaScript is no doubt an intractable language, it is clearly possible to do these things: many PHP/Python/Java toolsets have much better support.

I was wondering if there is a decent plug in for JavaScript in VS? Does everyone just suffer in silence, or am I missing something? I find the contrast between working in the C# side, which has awesome tools, to the JavaScript side which has tools with 1990s functionality quite disconcerting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking forward (it's not available as yet) to the JavaScript support in ReSharper 6: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/09/resharper-6-javascript-css-support-coming-up/

Comment: Well that is good news: I love ReSharper anyway, and JeBrains support for JavaScript in their other products is very good.

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty good too ..

http://code.google.com/p/js-addin